# ActionBarSherlock menu pops up normally

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I've got a SherlockListActivity, and am trying to have a button in the action bar. Here's my menu.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android=">http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:id="@+id/add"
    android:title="Add" 
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
</menu>
```

Here's my java code to show the menu:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
   MenuInflater inflater = this.getSupportMenuInflater();
   inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu, menu);
   return false;
}
```

But in my activity, the action bar shows, but with no button, and the menu button on my device does nothing. My device is running 2.3.3.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to return `true` from onCreateOptionsMenu().

Comment: Yes it does, I just had to wait a few minutes to accept the answer. Thank you again.